# What's the difference between including a variable as a mediator in a mediation analysis, and including a variable as a covariate in ANCOVA?

Tags: ancova, mediation

I understand that ANCOVA has a continuous outcome variable, and a categorical predictor, and (at least) one continuous covariate. Can this be run as a mediation model instead, and if so what are the differences between this and regular ANCOVA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in mediation the predictor X is theorized to cause Y, and this causal effect is theorized to depend (in whole, or substantially) via X causing the mediator M which in turn causes the outcome Y.

That causal chain need not be theorized in ANCOVA. In ANCOVA the predictor X need not be thought to plausibly exert any causal influence on the covariate C, or on the outcome via the covariate. In ANCOVA a rationale for including C is that it explains variation in the outcome variable and thus including it in the model improves the strength with which X predicts the outcome Y.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write yourconclusion as an answer, this is really valuable!